# My Steam client won't go online

Tags: steam

For some reason, when I powered my computer up and opened the Steam browser, it was in offline mode.  I didn't see it, so I opened Garry's Mod, and when I connected to a server, after about 10 seconds it said that it couldn't connect to VAC servers.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: I've had that one too, but to fix it I just clicked restart in online mode, and that basicaly fixed it.

Comment: Have you had this problem only once (which is what your question makes it sound like), or have you had this happen often?

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me every time I restart because *(due to my SSD)* Steam starts up faster than my computer can connect to my wireless network.

You can tell you're in offline mode because the steam-icon in the tray will be red.

[image: Steam Tray icon showing offline]              [image: Steam tray icon showing online]

To get back to online mode, you open Steam --> click the "Steam" menu in the upper-left --> *"Go Online..."*

[image: Steam menu showing "Go Online..."]

---

Of course, the **real** solution to my problem would be to make the wireless connect faster.  I've heard success stories from people doing this by updating their wireless-NIC drivers; unfortunately, that did not work for me.

Comment: A possible workaround to *your* problem is to make Steam not start on startup, and just start it manually as needed

Comment: You may also consider checking out [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/). It allows you to mark applications to delay launching so that system startup can finish faster. It does do a potentially scary amount of low-level integration with systems though, but the company seems reputable enough. I've had it installed for a few months and have been happy with it.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland: As you can see from my tray icons, I am already using Soluto :)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ha, you're right. My brain often fails me in the morning

Answer (score 2):

Open up your Steam window. In the top-left there is a button called "Steam". Click that, and then click "Go Online". Wait a few seconds, and Steam should be running in online mode.